# How can I wrap a class so that its methods are all passed a certain extra parameter by default?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following class that's been provided by an external library:

```
class ExampleClass {
    methodA(a, b, c) {}
    methodB(a, b, c) {}
    methodC(a, b, c) {}
}
```

How can I wrap this class, so that a value to parameter C is always provided, such that I can call the methods as normal, but leave out parameter C?

For example, let's assume parameter C is 20 by default, I can then do this:

`new ExampleClass().methodA(12, 14)`

And the resulting parameters are:

`a=12, b=14, c=20`

`new ExampleClass().methodB(39, 12)`

And the resulting parameters are:

`a=39, b=12, c=20`

`new ExampleClass().methodC(18, 14)`

And the resulting parameters are:

`a=18, b=14, c=20`

I've been doing some reading into ES6 Proxies, looks like apply() could work here, but I can't seem to get the implementation right.

EDIT: Also note that the method names are unpredictable and dynamically generated. I need to generically apply this. I can't extend the class and use super.

Comment: Is the value for `c` always constant, and not gonna change with any case?

Comment: `class C extends ExampleClass { methodA(a, b) { super.methodA(a, b, 20); } }`

Comment: @RaghavGarg, yes.

Comment: Maybe just use default parameters

Comment: @ASDFGerte, the class method names are dynamic and unpredictable. Needs to be generic rather than hardcoding method names.

Comment: @TomaszKleszczewski, the class is provided by a library, I can't change the method signatures

Comment: Are there always three parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example with a `Proxy`:

```js
class ExampleClass {
    methodA(a, b, c) {console.log('A', a, b, c)}
    methodB(a, b, c) {console.log('B', a, b, c)}
    methodC(a, b, c) {console.log('C', a, b, c)}
}

function ExampleClassWithC(obj, c) {
    return new Proxy(obj, {
        get(target, p) {
            if (typeof target[p] === 'function')
                return (a, b) => target[p](a, b, c)
            return target[p]
        }
    })
}

let c = ExampleClassWithC(new ExampleClass, 'myC')

c.methodA(1, 2)
c.methodB(3, 4)
c.methodC(5, 6)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!